# Swift enum Codable with associated types

Tags: swift, generics, codable

I have a struct with two types, both enum, one of them with different associated values in each enum case (see code). There's any workaround to avoid the switch on UDPCommand? Every case added makes the switch longer and kind of repeated code. And needs to be done on the encoder again. I'm trying to do it with generics but can't make it work. Thanks

```
struct UDPMessage {

    let command: UDPCommand
    var data: UDPCommandData

    func jsonString() -> String {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(self) else { return "" }
        guard let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return "" }
        return string
    }
}

enum UDPCommand: String, Codable {
    case DISCOVER
    case FILTER
    case TOGGLE
    case SWIPE_CHAT
    case FORWARD
}

enum UDPCommandData {
    case discover(Discover)
    case filter(Filter)
    case toggle(Toggle)
    case swipe(SwipeChat)
    case forwardedMessage(ForwardedMessage)
    case unkkown
}

extension UDPMessage: Codable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case command, data
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let command = try container.decode(UDPCommand.self, forKey: .command)

        switch command {
        case .DISCOVER:
            let data = try container.decode(Discover.self, forKey: .data)
            self.init(command: command, data: UDPCommandData.discover(data))
        case .FILTER:
            let data = try container.decode(Filter.self, forKey: .data)
            self.init(command: command, data: UDPCommandData.filter(data))
        case .TOGGLE:
            let data = try container.decode(Toggle.self, forKey: .data)
            self.init(command: command, data: UDPCommandData.toggle(data))
        case .SWIPE_CHAT:
            let data = try container.decode(SwipeChat.self, forKey: .data)
            self.init(command: command, data: UDPCommandData.swipe(data))
        default:
            self.init(command: command, data: UDPCommandData.unkkown)
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.command, forKey: .command)
        try self.data.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even need the custom `init(from:)` method? The compiler should be able to synthesise that automatically for you. Btw the cases of `UDPCommand` should conform to the Swift naming convention and be lowerCamelCase. You can simply assign the `String` rawValue as the uppercased version if that's what's coming in from the JSON. Like `enum UDPCommand: String, Codable {
    case discover = "DISCOVER"...`

Comment: @DávidPásztor, custom manual `init(from:)` for `UDPCommandData` would be required, because no auto code generation for `enum with associated value` implemented.